# Drawing a graph that is flat, but then spikes

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I'm trying to create a function that makes a graph like this:

```
|
|
|           -
|          - -
|         -   -
|        -     -
|--------       --------
|-----------------------
```

I'm stuck with: $1/((x-1.5)^2)$

Any help?

Comment: What about like a bell curve?

Comment: I used a tent function in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes such  functions are called [triangular or tent functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function).

The most basic example centered at $0$ looks like :
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1- |x|, & \text{if }|x|<1\\
0, & \text{ else}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I'd like it to be a curve ideally. Unfortunately, my graph doesn't really get that across very well...

Comment: Can I have an example of the function for this please, I can't work it out from wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

You can do $y=e^{-x^2}$ It isn't *exactly* flat on the sides, but it pretty much is. You can edit either the $e$, $2$, coefficient, or the denominator to change the shape (and translate it wherever you need).

As the comment below suggests, it's a Gaussian Curve.

Comment: such functions are often known as gaussian curves, see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the name for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your function to be *both* smooth and zero everywhere outside a finite interval, what you need is a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).  A classic example is $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-x^2)} & \text{for } -1 \le x \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ which looks like this:

$\hspace{70px}$[image: Plot of exp(-1/(1-x^2))]
<sup>(Image from Wikimedia Commons, created and released into the public domain by Oleg Alexandrov.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The function $1/(x-1.5)^2$ that you pointed couldn't have such that shape. But doing some changes can make it to have that desire shape. It is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1.5)^2}$$

[image]